# Java: Having trouble reading from a file

Tags: java, file, text

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.IOException;


public class TextFile {

private static void doReadWriteTextFile() {

    try {

        // input/output file names
        String inputFileName  = "README_InputFile.rtf";

        // Create FileReader Object
        FileReader inputFileReader   = new FileReader(inputFileName);

        // Create Buffered/PrintWriter Objects
        BufferedReader inputStream   = new BufferedReader(inputFileReader);


        while ((inLine = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(inLine);
        }

        inputStream.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        System.out.println("IOException:");
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    doReadTextFile();
}

}
```

I'm just learning Java, so take it easy on me. My program's objective is to read a text file and output it into another text file in reverse order. The problem is the professor taught us to to deal with strings and reverse it and such, but nothing about importing/exporting files. Instead, he gave us the following sample code which should import a file. The file returns 3 errors: The first two deal with inLine not being a symbol on lines 24 and 25. The last cannot find the symbol doReadTextFile on line 40.

I have no idea how to read this file and make the necessary changes to reverse and output into a new file. Any help is hugely appreciated.

I also had to change the file type from .txt to .rtf. I'm not sure if that affects how I need to go about this.

*EDIT* I defined inLine and fixed the doReadWritetextFile naming error, which fixed all my compiling errors. Any help on outputting into new file still appreciated!

I'm also aware he gave me bad sample code. It's supposed to be so we can learn troubleshooting, but with no working code to go off of and very extremely knowledge of the language, it's very difficult to see what's wrong. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Try defining `String inLine;` before the while loop. Also, your function is called `doReadWriteTextFile`, but you're calling `doReadTextFile`.

Comment: Your professor gave you bad sample code. In addition to the above change, also change `doReadTextFile();` to `doReadWriteTextFile();` or SkepticalFace can use the edit feature to make me look like I'm insane.

Comment: What do you mean by "you had to change the file type from txt to rtf"? Note that binary files != text files.

Comment: `.rtf` files are effectively 7 bit ASCII with markup escape sequences. If you read the file line by line it will NOT yield plain text unless it is an rtf file with no formatting: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format

Answer (score 1):

The good practice will be to use a BufferedFileReader

```
BufferedFileReader bf = new BufferedFileReader(new FileReader(new File("your_file.your_extention")));
```

Then you can read lines in your file :

```
// Initilisation of the inLine variable...
String inLine = null;

while((inLine = bf.readLine()) != null){
    System.out.println(inLine);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To output a file, you can use [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) to hold the file contents:

```
private static void doReadWriteTextFile() 
{
    ....
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while ((inLine = inputStream.readLine()) != null) 
    {
        sb.append(inline);
    }

     FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(new File("C:\\temp\\test.txt"));
     BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(writer);
     w.write(sb.toString());
     bw.close();
}
```